# Question about ordinal number

Tags: grammar

I give you a sentence below.

> She retained her tennis title for the third year.
>   ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/retain?q=retain))

'for' is a period of time and third is a ordinal number seeming plural, by the way 'year' is singlar form.

Is there any reason why it doesn't become 'years'?

Answer (score 4):

Your source actually says

> She retained her tennis title for **the** third year.

(**emphasis** mine.)

The article is there to indicate a particular year, the one identified by the ordinal "third." Ordinals aren't counts, like *three*. An ordinal indicates the place something has in a line of successors. *First* indicates the initial place; *second* indicates the next place; and *third* indicates the next place after second. There's only one place at a time: If the third year is 1920, that's the only year that can be third. Thus the word *year* is properly singular. You may, of course, talk about all the years she held her title by saying

> She retained her title for three years in a row.

Now you're counting the years, and as there is more than one, the word *years* is properly plural.